# where sould be put the behat.yml

Tags: behat

the documentation says

```
All configuration happens inside a single configuration file in the YAML format. Behat tries to load behat.yml or config/behat.yml by default, or you can tell Behat where your config file is with the --config option:
```

But I'm not sure If I have to put the file inside the root test folder or another places.

Thanks

Oskar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behat [looks for the configuration file](https://github.com/Behat/Behat/blob/f25ed953b98f11f4d073314b4edf4778b03c717e/src/Behat/Behat/ApplicationFactory.php#L111-L133) in the current working directory. In most cases that's going to be the root directory of your project (unless you run your tests by changing directory to the tests folder first).

```
my-project
 |- config
   \- behat.yml
 |- features
 |- tests
 |- vendor
 |- behat.yml
```

Behat will look for files named `behat.yaml`, `behat.yml`, `behat.yaml.dist`, `behat.yml.dist` (in this order). It will first try to find a config file in the root directory of your project, and in config directory second.

Specify the `--config` option if you'd like to put your config file somewhere else.